# How do I run go test with the -msan option on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: unit-testing, go, memory-leaks

When I try to run the go unit test system with the memory sanity checking I get an error message that I am sure I use to solve by setting my compiler to CLANG.

The [Go Command Documenation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) is a little brief on the matter.

```
-msan
    enable interoperation with memory sanitizer.
    Supported only on linux/amd64, linux/arm64
    and only with Clang/LLVM as the host C compiler.
    On linux/arm64, pie build mode will be used.
```

In the past I was use I got this to work by calling:

```
CC=clang go test -msan ./..
```

However when I do that now I get errors such as:

```
g++: error: unrecognized argument to -fsanitize= option: ‘memory’
```

What do I need to do in order to run my golang tests with the memory sanitizer under Ubuntu 18:04 ?

---

I am using the following versions of tools at the moment:

```
$ go version
go version go1.14 linux/amd64
$ clang --version
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Comment: It seems I may have found something relavent.  One of the packages that I import includes C++ code now.  CC=clang deals with setting the C Compiler but not the C++ Compiler.  When I run with CC=clang CXX=clang I get a new error message for me to investigate.  The clue probably should have been the mention of g++ (which can be both a C and C++ compiler).

Comment: Fixed the last error message.  Clang does not default to assuming .h files are C++ files so you need to add `// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lstdc++` in some go files if you are not using .hpp for C++ files.  My problem seems to have turned up after a dependant project added C++ as well as C files, which meant I then needed to add `CXX=clang` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires a version of LLVM that supports *-fsanitize=memory* on your version of *Ubuntu 18.04* that the program runs on. Please try updating and then try it again.

Also do note, on *Linux* you need at least *LLVM 3.8* to get the *-fsanitize* flag.

The *Go* tool automatically adds the -fsanitize=memory option to *CGO_CPPFLAGS* flag as required by clang for linking and that's where it's resulting in an error for you.

Also, make sure to add both *CC* and *CXX* (for *clang++*) flags so to enable compilation using *Clang* when you're interop your program with *C/C++* i.e.,

```golang
CC=clang CXX=clang++ go build -msan
```

**Also do refer this link**:

https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/go1.7/misc/cgo/testsanitizers/test.bash (bash script)

(or)

https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/misc/cgo/testsanitizers (*.go files)

It will help you test the sanitizers if they would work on your setup or not.

Comment: The go1.7 & go1.14 tests are quite different.  The script completes silently which I guess means it passed.  Running each step one at a time seems to suggest it is passing too.  Similary the .go based tests from go1.14 also pass. All as expected as I am using either Clang 3.8 or 6.0 which both count.  So there must be soemthing in the project I am working on that is breaking the msan part of the build.  I will check further.

Comment: Your suggestions helped me gain confidence that things must be working on my development system and that the problem lay somewhere in the project code (which was a resonable certainty anyway).  If you could update it to include a little more about using Clag for C and C++ if it is not the default I would happily accept it as the answer.

Comment: `env CC=clang env CXX=clang++ go build -msan` Try this and share the error message.

Comment: I have it working with `CC=clang CXX=clang++ go build -msan` sorry I did not make that clear in my previous comment.  I had mumbled some notes into the comments of my Question but not your answer.  

If you could add some hints to the next reader that you may need to set both the CC and CXX to clang for Ubuntu then I would happily accept your answer.